# PIG Error : while reading the Attribute from a Relation

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

​Hi,
I am Using the below code to perform the Order Operation but it throwing the error that `Invalid field projection` where As the The Relation Has the column.

`grunt> byts = ORDER B BY JB_DLT::job_id DESC;`

**ERROR**

> 2016-09-20 07:32:56,815 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1025:  Invalid field projection. Projected field [JB_DLT::job_id] does not exist in schema:
>   group:tuple(JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id:bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_cd:chararray),a:bag{:tuple(JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id:bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_cd:chararray,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_id:bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::actual_status_dt:datetime)}.

`grunt> describe B;`

> B: {group: (JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id:
>   bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_cd: chararray),a:
>   {(JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id:
>   bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_cd:
>   chararray,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::job_assignment_status_id:
>   bigdecimal,JOB_ASNMNT_STS_DLT::actual_status_dt: datetime)}}

How to read this column data in the ORDER BY Clause. Please share your thoughts..

Comment: either use 'job_id' or 'JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id'

Answer (score 1):

Though **JB_DLT::job_id**  exists but Pig latin is not able to find (there is JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id),edit the statement B adding JB_DLT::job_id as job_id . then run:

`grunt> byts = ORDER B BY job_id DESC`;

Or

```
byts = ORDER B BY JB_ASGNMNT::JB_DLT::job_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ORDER BY on a grouped data. Use FOREACH to generate the required data and then perform ORDER BY.

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (job_id, job_assignment_status_cd), a;
byts = ORDER C BY job_id DESC;
```